# How to initialize a string with special characters `"`?

Tags: java

```
String res=""id":"565","value":"Y"";
```

How to initialize `"id":"565","value":"Y"` to a string?

Answer (score 3):

you need to escape the `"` characters:

```
String res="\"id\":\"565\",\"value\":\"Y\""
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a backwards slash `\` as an escape string when you want to include `"` in a String

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the special characters like this :

`String s = "String res=\"\"id\":\"565\",\"value\":\"Y\"";`

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the special characters by adding \ before the special characters.

Do like this.

```
String res="\"id\":\"565\",\"value\":\"Y\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

use escape character to store special strings

```
String res="\"id\":\"565\",\"value\":\"Y\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the special characters by using \ OR \\

For e.g.
String res="\"id\":\"565\",\"value\":\"Y\""

OR

String res="\\"id\\":\\"565\\",\\"value\\":\\"Y\\""

For more details visit these two links
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html