# Selenium using xPath String

Tags: java, string, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
WebElement element_enter = Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="collapseClientInfo"]/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/input"));
element_enter.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="collapseClientInfo"]/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("TSS");
```

It shows an error message

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: This code looks OK. Are you sure the error is here?

Comment: Yes, it shows same error.

Comment: Sometimes, it shows "Syntax error on token "collapseClientInfo", invalid AssignmentOperator" for the same line.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes, it shows "Syntax error on token "collapseClientInfo", invalid AssignmentOperator" for the same line

Actually you are using [`xpath` String with special `"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629250/how-to-initialize-a-string-with-special-characters), That's why you are in trouble.

You should use `\` to escape `"` character as below :

```
WebElement element_enter = Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"collapseClientInfo\"]/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/input"));
element_enter.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"collapseClientInfo\"]/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("TSS");
```

or you can use `'` instead of `"` as below :-

```
WebElement element_enter = Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='collapseClientInfo']/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/input"));
element_enter.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='collapseClientInfo']/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("TSS");
```

---

**Reference link** :-

- [How to initialize a string with special characters `"`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629250/how-to-initialize-a-string-with-special-characters)
- [Java - How to put special characters into a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513610/java-how-to-put-special-characters-into-a-string)

Comment: Thanks, Saurabh. Single quote works for me.                                                        Could you please help me for value operator as well, suppose for a field we've value but we don't have ID so how we can call that field with value for entering text?

Comment: @ajaykumar what do you mean by value?? element's visible inner text or element's attribute value??

Comment: Inner text Saurabh

Comment: @ajaykumar for innert text, you can find an element as `.//*[text() = 'inner text']`..

Comment: @ajaykumar for reference follow [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329436/selenium-xpath-selector-based-on-the-element-text)